converting ISO 8601 timestamp syntax from zulu to local in C
I am working within a C code with a timestamp syntax given from another program as 2024-08-27T14:07:48.044785Z
I know I can do date +%Z and see either EDT or EST to then know to subtract either 4 hours or 5, and then see if I have to roll back the day, and then possibly the month, and year....
what's the best/easiest/correct way to handle this given the timestamp syntax is in zulu getting it converted to local ?

Depending on your OS, you might have a strptime to convert the string to a struct tm.

That format is one ISO 8601 standard format.  Getting the fractional sections converted is where life will get interesting.  The POSIX strptime() function takes a struct tm * and that doesn't have sub-second data.  However, strptime() will identify that the conversion stopped on the . before the fractional seconds, which allows you to take it from there.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618111/iso-8601-to-time-t-conversion-in-c-or-vice-versa https://linux.die.net/man/3/getdate . What system are you working on? What C standard library are you working with?

basic RHEL-8.10 x86-64 install and gcc 8.5.0;  simple compile via gcc -W reformattest.c -o reformattest.x

quite old, but most probably you have getdate_r and getdate

@ron "I know I can do date +%Z" is trickier to do than one first thinks on date/times near daylights shifts. Please post how one gets a UTC timestamp and then a local time zone offset (without first getting the local timestamp).

Using standard library functions (and not knowing the time zone offset):

Convert string to struct tm using sscanf().
Convert struct tm to time_t.
Convert time_t to local struct tm.


With C2X (and possible with select other versions of C) is time_t timegm(struct tm *timeptr) which converts a tm structure, of universal time to time_t.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
/*
 Convert a 8601 formatted string of UTC time to a local struct tm one.
 Fractional seconds are discarded.
 Return the `time_t` and -1 on error.
*/
time_t utc_string_to_local_tm(struct tm *dest, const char *utc) {
  // 2024-08-27T14:07:48.044785Z
  *dest = (struct tm) {0}; // Set all members to 0.
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(utc, "%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:%d.%*ldZ%n", &dest->tm_year, &dest->tm_mon,
      &dest->tm_mday, &dest->tm_hour, &dest->tm_min, &dest->tm_sec, &n);
  // If scan failed or incomplete ...
  if (n == 0 || utc[n]) {
    return -1;
  }

  // Adjust some members
  dest->tm_year -= 1900;
  dest->tm_mon--;

  /*
  If known, code could add the time zone offset to .tm_hour here
  and then call mktime() to re-adjust members.
  In which case we are done.
  Yet I assert getting that offset is non-trivial in corner cases of
  daylight savings time changes and the rare time zone adjustments.
  */

  time_t t = timegm(dest);
  if (t == -1) {
    return -1;
  }

  // Convert t to a local tm.
  struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
  if (tm == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }
  *dest = *tm;

  return t;
}

int main() {
  struct tm tm;
  time_t t = utc_string_to_local_tm(&tm, "2024-08-27T14:07:48.044785Z");
  printf("%lld %s", (long long) t, asctime(&tm));
}


Without C2X, there are various ways to use existing standard library functions to perform timegm(), yet I find those approaches fail corner cases (near daylight savings time changes).
